# (Python) How to get combination of a list

Tags: python, combinations

I have a list of strings like :

```
['blue','red','white','black']
```

The result for this list will be something that has all the combinations split into two/

Such as the followings (2^4 - 1) cases:

```
['blue']['red','white','black']
['red']['blue','white','black']
['white']['blue','red','black']
['black']['blue','white','red']
['blue','red']['white','black']
['blue','white']['red','black']
['blue','black']['white','red']
```

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Hi there, Have you tried an approach to what you are trying to have happen using code that could be included in your post? :)

Comment: Could [this](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.set_partitions) be what you need?